# Does the Jquery validation plugin require a form tag?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate some asp.net textboxes with the jQuery Validation plugin found at 
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation, but it appears that the elements must be between a form tag.  If I have just a couple elements, I would hardly call that a form, so I would rather not have them wrapped inside a form element.  Is there a way around this?  Also,  if I have two buttons on the form, a cancel and a submit button and I want the form only to validate when the submit button is clicked, but not the cancel button, how is this accomplished?

Comment: A form is how you tell the browser where to send the data. Without one the controls are useless … unless you fake having a form in JavaScript, which violates rule 2: http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build

Comment: What about the second part of the question, only validating if a submit button is clicked for example.  I have a cancel button which when clicked, should do nothing, but it still validates the form.

Comment: You doing full post backs? Like if your cancel button just clears the fields why make it a submit button? And not a button? If you make it I button I don't think it will trigger the validation. You could make them both buttons and in one button it would call the  submit method(you would make on in jquery). Then the next like would be using the valid() method that comes with jquery validation. This way you can do like an ajax post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have just a couple elements, I would
>   hardly call that a form, so I would
>   rather not have them wrapped inside a
>   form element.

If the elements are not within a form tag, then it is not a valid HTML document, so behavior within script might get wonky depending on how the browser deals with the malformed HTML.

Most browsers will create a form implicitly, but now you have no control over the form's behavior. The defaults are usually be a post action form targeted at the requested page's URL.

The problem is, you probably have no idea what selector to use in the JQuery to get a reference to the form... but I suppose `$("form")` would do the trick.

> validate when the submit button is clicked, but not the cancel button

The plug-in intercepts and runs on the submit event of a form. Generally cancel buttons are html input elements with the type attribute set to "reset":

```
<input type="reset" value="cancel" />
```

A reset type button will not cause the form to submit, and this will not trigger the validation.

If you use another button type, make sure the onclick even returns false. This cancels the form's submit action but still allows you to run javasctipt of your own when the button is clicked.

Comment: I am using an asp:Button for the Cancel and Submit.

Comment: I actually figured out the second part. I set the UseSubmitBehavior property to false for the cancel button and it made it a regular input type=button instead of a type=submit and that solved the issue.  I decided to use the LiveValidation script.  It works pretty well.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The jquery validate plugin requires a form element to function, so you should have your form fields (no matter how few) contained inside a form.

You can tell the validation plugin not to operate on form submission, then manually validate the form when the correct submit button is clicked.

For example, using a class to identify the correct submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $("form");

  form.validate({
    onsubmit: false,
  });

  //Validate form only if validation submit button is clicked
  //Allows cancel submit buttons to function properly
  $('.validate', form).click(function() {
    if (form.valid()) {
      form.submit();
    }
    else {
      form.validate().form();
    }
  });

});
```